# How can I count the invocations of a method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, interceptor

Use interceptors to count the number of invocations.

I created an application with java ee consisting of an ejb side and a client. Now I have to count the number of times the client invokes a method, for each method, using the interceptors.

I don't understand how to modify the interceptors class. This is my code.

```
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class InterceptorsBean {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object methodInterceptors (InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {        
        System.out.println("Method invocated: " + ctx.getMethod().getName());
        return ctx.proceed();
    }    

}
```

How can I add the function to count?

Comment: count=count+1???

Comment: I have to count the number of times for each method, using count ++ I get the total number of calls

Comment: Hold a `Map<String, Integer>` with the method name as key and the counter as value. Then increment the counter if the method is entered. Maybe one map per class with the methods of that class. You could provide another method that outputs this map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map to hold the method name and the number of invocations of that method.

```
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;
import java.util.Map;

public class InterceptorsBean {

    private Map<String, Integer> numberOfInvocations;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object methodInterceptors (InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        int invocations = 1;

        if(numberOfInvocations.containsKey(ctx.getMethod().getName())) {
           invocations = numberOfInvocations.get(ctx.getMethod().getName()) + 1;
        }

        numberOfInvocations.put(ctx.getMethod().getName(), invocations);

        System.out.println("Method invocated: " + ctx.getMethod().getName());
        System.out.println("Number of invocations: " + invocations);
        return ctx.proceed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize a field to 0 and then increment it whenever the method is entered.

If the method is static, then make it a static field.

And make the variable private and use an instance or static method as appropriate to retrieve it.  This is so others who can invoke the method can't change the variable.

If you want to do this for multiple methods, use a map and use the method name as a key to retrieve the appropriate counter.

```java
public class MapCounterDemo {

   private Map<String, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MapCounterDemo demo = new MapCounterDemo();
      demo.foo();
      demo.foo();
      demo.foo();
      demo.bar();
      demo.bar();
      System.out.println(demo.counters);
   }

   public void foo() {
      update("foo");

   }

   public void bar() {
      update("bar");
   }

   private void update(String method) {
      counters.compute(method,
            (k, v) -> v == null ? 1
                  : ++v);

   }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to do it for multiple methods. What do you mean to create a map? Do I create an external class with a constructor and methods for set and restoring the count to me?